# c#: get the attribute's xpath for an xml element

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

**Given the following XML:**

```
<enrollment>
    <school>
        <students>
            <studentA fname="John" lname="Doe" age="23" />
            <studentB fname="Mary" lname="Johnson" age="22" /> 
        </students>  
    </school>  
</enrollment>
```

and here's my code to iterate the attributes-

```
foreach(XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
{
    //--get the XPath for each attribute 
}
```

Where node = "studentA", how do I get the XPath for each attribute?

**EDIT:** 
Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is to compare if two nodes are the same. So I have to check if they have the **same name, attributes, and attribute values**. Therefore given a node, I need an xpath expression that that matches the conditions stated.

Comment: Which part of checking whether they have the "**same name, attributes, and attribute values**" requires knowing the XPaths of the attributes?

Comment: @JLRishi I forgot to mention that the two nodes to be compared are from different XML files. Given a node on xml1, I will get its xpath and use it to find if a similar node exists on xml2. But hey thanks for making things clear, I realized that what I really need is the xpath for the node and the attributes are the conditions for that xpath expression.

Answer (score 2):

you can directly put it like as for all  the studentA nodes-

Xpath- `"//studentA"`

or to iterate over a specific node-
Xpath- `"enrollment/school/students/studentA"`

In case you want to find attribute fname

Xpath- `"enrollment/school/students/studentA[@fname]"`

Assuming myXml is your xmlDocument
you can iterate over a particular node attributes like-

```
        System.Xml.XmlNode xn =  myXml.SelectSingleNode("enrollment/school/students/studentA");
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlAttribute attrib in xn.Attributes)
        {
            // find attribute name using attrib.Name
            string sAttribName = attrib.Name;
            if (sAttribName == "fname")
            {
                //Check your codes here
            }               
        }
```

Comment: +1 for this, I can now get the element with an attribute of fname, but can u also show me an xpath expression that would match if an element has more than 1 attribute. e.g fname, lname, age

Comment: @wintersolstice, Are you using XMLDocument or Linq to XML ?

Comment: I'm using XMLDocument, I found out that there are also logical operators for xpath. e.g. 'and' and 'or', i think i could use that

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use enrollment/school/students/studentA/@fname
```

@attribute is for attribute selection.

Comment: Rohit's answer is correct. Mine has a typo. It should be enrollment/school/students/studentA[@fname]